# Real faithful representations of $\mathrm{SL}(2,5)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-topology, representation-theory

What is the minimal degree of a real faithful representation of the binary dihedral group $\mathrm{SL}(2,5)$?

Is there actually a unified way how to determine such minimal dimension (over the field of real numbers) for a finite group?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your first question is $4$. There is a $2$-dimensional faithful complex representation of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ with real character values, but its representation is not realizable over the real field.

Its Schur Index is $2$, which means that the direct sum of two copies of this representation can be represented over ${\mathbb R}$.

I guess the answer to your second question is yes in the sense that there exist algorithms to compute the character table of a finite group, and also to compute Schur Indexes.